# cudnn error when runnung pytorch on Google Colab

Tags: pytorch

Since yesterday when I try to run Pytorch using GPU on Google Colab I recieve the error provided below. Previously it worked fine. I have tried to install different versions of Pytorch and I have got different errors.

```
# Use PyTorch to check versions, CUDA version and cuDNN

import torch

print("PyTorch version: ")
print(torch.__version__)
print("CUDA Version: ")
print(torch.version.cuda)
print("cuDNN version is: ")
print(torch.backends.cudnn.version())
```

PyTorch version:
1.12.0+cu113

CUDA Version:
11.3

cuDNN version is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-23-93b5c974c4be> in <module>()
      8 print(torch.version.cuda)
      9 print("cuDNN version is: ")
---> 10 print(torch.backends.cudnn.version())

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/backends/cudnn/__init__.py in version()
     48 def version():
     49     """Returns the version of cuDNN"""
---> 50     if not _init():
     51         return None
     52     return __cudnn_version
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/backends/cudnn/__init__.py in _init()
     39                 raise RuntimeError(
     40                     'cuDNN version incompatibility: PyTorch was compiled against {} '
---> 41                     'but linked against {}'.format(compile_version, runtime_version))
     42         return True
     43 else:

RuntimeError: cuDNN version incompatibility: PyTorch was compiled against (8, 3, 2) but linked against (8, 0, 5)
```

Comment: Check how to ask questions i.e. minimum code that reproduces the error.

Comment: I just started learning PyTorch and i have the same problem on my colab, when trying to move my code from local to colab. Hope that someone has the solution. It is probably some versions mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to upgrade Python to newer version(3.9), this solved a problem for me.

```
!wget -O mini.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x mini.sh
!bash ./mini.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y jupyter
!conda install -q -y google-colab -c conda-forge
!python -m ipykernel install --name "py39" --user
```

Comment: any other ideas? After following those steps it still doesn't work for me. I've tried restarting the runtime as well as other ideas. Any thoughts?